# "KeyError" for PySimpleGUI Project Integration

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have been trying to integrate a new page into a project i am doing.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
def page2b():

    company_list_column = [
        [sg.Text('Pick your company name')],
        [sg.Listbox(os.listdir("C:\/FYP\/GUI\/Companies"), size=(25, 5), key='-EC-', enable_events=True)]
    ]
    company_column = [
        [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-Company Selected-')],
        [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-Folder Selected-')],  
    ]
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Select your Company', justification='center',font=("Arial",22))],
        [
        sg.Column(company_list_column),
        sg.VSeparator(),
        sg.Column(company_column),
        ],
        [sg.Button('Select Company'), sg.Button('Close')]
    ]
    return sg.Window('Baseline Analyzer', layout, default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(12, 1), size=(600,270))
window= page2b() 
while True:                  # the event loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Close":
        break
    if values['-EC-']:    # if something is highlighted in the list
        window['-Company Selected-'].update(f"Company selected: {values['-EC-'][0]}")
        window['-Folder Selected-'].update(f"Your folder is: C:\FYP\GUI\Companies\{values['-EC-'][0]}")
    if event == "Select Company": #The path of the folder to store the things at
        word= {values['-EC-'][0]}
        word = "".join(word)
        foldername = "C:\FYP\\GUI\\Companies\\" + word
        break
window.close()
```

In summary, this would display a list of company folders for me to choose from and when i click on an folder, i would see what is indeed the selected folder, as exampled in the below screenshot:

[image]

As a standalone progam, the above page works absolutely fine. However, the moment i try to integrate it into my main program, as evidenced down below:

```
from tkinter.constants import UNDERLINE
from tkinter.font import BOLD, ITALIC
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time     
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('DarkTeal9')           

# ------ Menu Definition ------ #      
menu_def = [
    ['Company Selection',['New Company','Existing Company']],
    ['Help',['How to use']]
]
menu_def2 = [
    ['Scan Management', ['Start Audit Task']],      
    ['Baseline Management',  ['View Baselines'] ],      
    ['Help', ['How to Use']] 
]    

# ------ Functions Defintion ------ #
def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        if key != 'Import Host':
            window[key]('')
    return None  

def folder_gen():
    clientFolder = os.mkdir(values['New Client Name'])  

# ------ GUI Defintion ------ #
def page1():

    layout = [
        [sg.Menu(menu_def)],
        [sg.Text('Welcome to the Baseline Analyzer!', justification='center',font=("Arial",25, BOLD))],
        [sg.Button('New Company')],
        [sg.Button('Existing Company')],
        [sg.Button('Exit')],
    ]
    return sg.Window('Baseline Analyzer', layout,element_justification='c', default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_text=False, auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(25, 3), size=(600,270), finalize=True)

def page_2a():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('New Company Name: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='New Client Name')],
        [sg.Text('Date of Registration: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Date')],
        [sg.Text('Location of Site: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Location')],
        [sg.Text('Department: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Department')],
        [sg.Text('Company Liaison Name: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Liaison')],
        [sg.Text('Company Liaison Email: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Contact')],
        [sg.Text('Company Liaison Number: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Number')],
        [sg.Button('Create Company'), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
    ]      

    return sg.Window('Generate Client Profile', layout,element_justification='c', default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_text=False, auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(12, 1), size=(600,270), finalize=True)

def page2b():

    company_list_column = [
        [sg.Text('Pick your company name')],
        [sg.Listbox(os.listdir("C:\/FYP\/GUI\/Companies"), size=(25, 5), key='-EC-', enable_events=True)]
    ]

    company_column = [
        [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-Company Selected-')],
        [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-Folder Selected-')],
        
    ]

    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Select your Company', justification='center',font=("Arial",22))],
        [
        sg.Column(company_list_column),
        sg.VSeparator(),
        sg.Column(company_column),
        ],
        [sg.Button('Select Company'), sg.Button('Close')]
    ]

    return sg.Window('Baseline Analyzer', layout, default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(12, 1), size=(600,270), finalize=True)

window1, window2= page1(), None                  

# ------ Loop & Process button menu choices ------ #  
    # ------ Process menu choices ------ #      

while True:      
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
        window.close()
        if window == window2:
            window2 = None
        elif window == window1:
            break           
    # Clear New Scan form inputs
    elif event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
        #Exisiting Company selection page
    if event == 'New Company':
        window = page_2a()    
    elif event == 'Existing Company':
        window = page2b()
        if values['-EC-']:    # if something is highlighted in the list
            window['-Company Selected-'].update(f"Company selected: {values['-EC-'][0]}")
            window['-Folder Selected-'].update(f"Your folder is: C:\FYP\GUI\Companies\{values['-EC-'][0]}")
        if event == "Select Company": #The path of the folder to store the things at
            word= {values['-EC-'][0]}
            word = "".join(word)
            foldername = "C:\FYP\\GUI\\Companies\\" + word
        
window.close()
```

I am presented with this "keyError" and have been racking my head on how to solve it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\******\Documents\******\******\testing.py", line 140, in <module>
    if values['-EC-']:    # if something is highlighted in the list
KeyError: '-EC-'
```

Is there a solution to my predicament?

Comment: You got everythong mixed together ! `event` and `values` were from which window event generated and from method `read`. So you can not get value of element in window1 by `values1` read from window2. You cannot get the most update `values` without method `read`.

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you have in variables.

Comment: It would be simpler if every window will run own `while`-loop.

Comment: as for me `window = page2b()` create new window but it doesnt't update information in ` window, event, values` and it would need to run `sg.read_all_windows()` to get new inromation. And it may need also to check first `if '- EC -' in values`. But then I see other problem because you use the same name `window` in `window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()` and `window = page2b()` so it can makes some other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `window = page2b()` creates new window but it doesn't update values in `window, event, values` - it would need to run again `sg.read_all_windows()`

So you should run `if values['-EC-']` directly in `while True`. But it will be execute for every window so you would have to check `if '-EC-' in values and values['-EC-']` or you would have to check `if window == window2` but it needs also use `window2 = page2b()` instead of `window = page2b()` or even better `window2b = page2b()` to recognize if you run `page2a` or `page2b`

```
# ---

window1 = page1()
window2a = None
window2b = None

while True:      
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    #print('window:', window)
    #print('event:', event)
    #print('values:', values)
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
        window.close()
        if window == window2a:
            window2a = None
        elif window == window2b:
            window2b = None
        elif window == window1:
            break           
    elif event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()

    # - events, values unique for every window -

    if window == window1:
        if event == 'New Company':
            window2a = page_2a()    
        elif event == 'Existing Company':
            window2b = page2b()

    elif window == window2a:
        # ... code ...
        pass
    
    elif window == window2b:
        if values['-EC-']:
            window['-Company Selected-'].update(f"Company selected: {values['-EC-'][0]}")
            window['-Folder Selected-'].update(f"Your folder is: C:\FYP\GUI\Companies\{values['-EC-'][0]}")
        if event == "Select Company":
            word = {values['-EC-'][0]}
            word = "".join(word)
            foldername = "C:\FYP\\GUI\\Companies\\" + word
   
window.close()
```

Or even

```
window1 = page1()
window2a = None
window2b = None

while True:      
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    #print('window:', window)
    #print('event:', event)
    #print('values:', values)
    
    if window == window1:
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
            window.close()
            break
        elif event == 'New Company':
            window2a = page_2a()    
        elif event == 'Existing Company':
            window2b = page2b()

    elif window == window2a:
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
            window.close()
            window2a = None
        elif event == 'Clear':
            clear_input()
    
    elif window == window2b:
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
            window.close()
            window2b = None
        elif values['-EC-']:
            window['-Company Selected-'].update(f"Company selected: {values['-EC-'][0]}")
            window['-Folder Selected-'].update(f"Your folder is: C:\FYP\GUI\Companies\{values['-EC-'][0]}")
        elif event == "Select Company":
            word = {values['-EC-'][0]}
            word = "".join(word)
            foldername = "C:\\FYP\\GUI\\Companies\\" + word
```

---

**EDIT:**

Other idea is to create for every window new `while`-loop but sometimes it may work different then previous version. When `window2` is opened then it blocks buttons in `window1` so you can't open two `windows 2` at the same time. Previous version can open `New Company','Existing Company` at the same time - it may even open many `Existing Company` and many 'New Company `at the same time. This version can open only one 'New Company` or only one `Existing Company` and it can open `New Company','Existing Company` at the same time.

And in new version you can't use `Exit` in `window1` when `window2` is open.

I changed path in `listdir()` to run it on my system.

```
from tkinter.constants import UNDERLINE
from tkinter.font import BOLD, ITALIC
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import time     
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH

sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('DarkTeal9')           

# ------ Menu Definition ------ #    

menu_def = [
    ['Company Selection',['New Company','Existing Company']],
    ['Help',['How to use']]
]
menu_def2 = [
    ['Scan Management', ['Start Audit Task']],      
    ['Baseline Management',  ['View Baselines'] ],      
    ['Help', ['How to Use']] 
]    

# ------ Functions Defintion ------ #

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        if key != 'Import Host':
            window[key]('')
    return None  

def folder_gen():
    clientFolder = os.mkdir(values['New Client Name'])  

# ------ GUI Defintion ------ #
def page1():

    layout = [
        [sg.Menu(menu_def)],
        [sg.Text('Welcome to the Baseline Analyzer!', justification='center',font=("Arial",25, BOLD))],
        [sg.Button('New Company')],
        [sg.Button('Existing Company')],
        [sg.Button('Exit')],
    ]
    
    window = sg.Window('Baseline Analyzer', layout,element_justification='c', default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_text=False, auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(25, 3), size=(600,270), finalize=True)

    while True:      
        event, values = window.read()
        #print('window:', window)
        #print('event:', event)
        #print('values:', values)
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
            window.close()
            return
        elif event == 'New Company':
            page_2a()    
        elif event == 'Existing Company':
            page2b()

def page_2a():
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('New Company Name: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='New Client Name')],
        [sg.Text('Date of Registration: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Date')],
        [sg.Text('Location of Site: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Location')],
        [sg.Text('Department: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Department')],
        [sg.Text('Company Liaison Name: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Liaison')],
        [sg.Text('Company Liaison Email: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Contact')],
        [sg.Text('Company Liaison Number: ', size=(20,1)), sg.InputText(key='Number')],
        [sg.Button('Create Company'), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
    ]      

    window = sg.Window('Generate Client Profile', layout,element_justification='c', default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_text=False, auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(12, 1), size=(600,270), finalize=True)

    while True:      
        event, values = window.read()
        #print('window:', window)
        #print('event:', event)
        #print('values:', values)
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
            window.close()
            return
        elif event == 'Clear':
            clear_input()

def page2b():

    company_list_column = [
        [sg.Text('Pick your company name')],
        [sg.Listbox(os.listdir(), size=(25, 5), key='-EC-', enable_events=True)]
    ]

    company_column = [
        [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-Company Selected-')],
        [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-Folder Selected-')],
        
    ]

    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Select your Company', justification='center',font=("Arial",22))],
        [
        sg.Column(company_list_column),
        sg.VSeparator(),
        sg.Column(company_column),
        ],
        [sg.Button('Select Company'), sg.Button('Close')]
    ]

    window = sg.Window('Baseline Analyzer', layout, default_element_size=(100, 1), auto_size_buttons=False,      
                     default_button_element_size=(12, 1), size=(600,270), finalize=True)

    while True:      
        event, values = window.read()
        #print('window:', window)
        #print('event:', event)
        #print('values:', values)
        
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit'or event =='Close':
            window.close()
            return
        elif values['-EC-']:
            window['-Company Selected-'].update(f"Company selected: {values['-EC-'][0]}")
            window['-Folder Selected-'].update(f"Your folder is: C:\FYP\GUI\Companies\{values['-EC-'][0]}")
        if event == "Select Company":
            word = {values['-EC-'][0]}
            word = "".join(word)
            foldername = "C:\\FYP\\GUI\\Companies\\" + word

# --- start ---

page1()
```